# Error when trying to GET/POST data in PostgreSQL using Spring Data JPA REST APIs

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 3 to create basic REST APIs, and trying to get content from PostgreSQL and post there too. I looked up every documentation and tutorial but GET gives an Error 500 while POST gives an Error 400. The APIs were working perfectly with the usual get, getById and post logic coded in the content repository. They stop working when trying to use Spring Data JPA.

UPDATE 1: GET is working by removing 'desc', POST still giving error 400

UPDATE 2: It was the damn enum. SOLVED

[postman get error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PQLH.png)

[postman post error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJpMh.png)

[postgres table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jac5U.png)

Here's the code.

Content Model

```
package com.project.test.example.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        Integer id;
        @NotBlank
        @Column(name = "title")
        String title;
        @NotBlank
        @Column(name = "desc")
        String desc;

        @Column(name = "status")
        Status status;

        @Column(name = "type")
        Type type;

        @Column(name = "dateCreated")
        LocalDateTime dateCreated;

        @Column(name = "dateUpdated")
        LocalDateTime dateUpdated;

        @Column(name = "url")
        String url;

        public Content(Integer id, String title, String desc, Status status, Type type, LocalDateTime dateCreated, LocalDateTime dateUpdated, String url) {
                this.id = id;
                this.title = title;
                this.desc = desc;
                this.status = status;
                this.type = type;
                this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
                this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
                this.url = url;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
                return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
                this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
                return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
                this.title = title;
        }

        public String getDesc() {
                return desc;
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
                this.desc = desc;
        }

        public Status getStatus() {
                return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(Status status) {
                this.status = status;
        }

        public Type getType() {
                return type;
        }

        public void setType(Type type) {
                this.type = type;
        }

        public LocalDateTime getDateCreated() {
                return dateCreated;
        }

        public void setDateCreated(LocalDateTime dateCreated) {
                this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        }

        public LocalDateTime getDateUpdated() {
                return dateUpdated;
        }

        public void setDateUpdated(LocalDateTime dateUpdated) {
                this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
                return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
                this.url = url;
        }
}
```

Content JpaRepository Interface

```
package com.project.test.example.repository;

import com.project.test.example.model.Content;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface ContentJPARespository extends JpaRepository<Content, Integer> {

}
```

Content Service

```
package com.project.test.example.service;

import com.project.test.example.model.Content;
import com.project.test.example.repository.ContentJPARespository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ContentService {
    @Autowired
    private ContentJPARespository repo;

    public Content saveContent(Content con){
        return repo.save(con);
    }

    public List<Content> getContent(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }


}
```

Content Controller (The commented code was the one working without Spring JPA, the ContentCollectionRepository is below this controller)

```
package com.project.test.example.controller;

import com.project.test.example.model.Content;
import com.project.test.example.repository.ContentCollectionRepository;
import com.project.test.example.repository.ContentJPARespository;
import com.project.test.example.service.ContentService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/content") // url to access apis
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@Tag(name = "Content") // swagger controller name
public class ContentController {
//    private final ContentCollectionRepository repository; //dependency injection of ContentCollectionRepository
//    public ContentController(ContentCollectionRepository repository) { // constructor
//        this.repository = repository;
//    }

    @Autowired
    private ContentService service;

//    // get all content
//    @GetMapping("/getAll")
//    public List<Content> finAll() {
//        return repository.findAll();
//    }

    // get all content
    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Content> findAll() {
        return service.getContent();
    }

//    // get content by id
//    @GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
//    public Content findById(@PathVariable Integer id) { // @PathVariable is like useParams() in react
//        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Content not found"));
//    }

//    // create new content
//    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
//    @PostMapping("/create")
//    public void create(@Valid @RequestBody Content content) {
//        repository.save(content);
//    }

    // create new content
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public Content saveCon(@RequestBody Content content) {
        return service.saveContent(content);
    }


//    // update content by id
//    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
//    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
//    public void update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Content content) {
//        if (!repository.existsById(id)) {
//            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Id must be greater than 0");
//        }
//        repository.save(content);
////        repository.updateById(id, content);
//
//    }
//
//    // delete content by id
//    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
//    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
//    public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
//        if (!repository.existsById(id)) {
//            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Id must be greater than 0");
//        }
//        repository.delete(id);
//    }

}
```

ContentCollectionRepository

```
package com.project.test.example.repository;

import com.project.test.example.model.Content;
import com.project.test.example.model.Status;
import com.project.test.example.model.Type;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public class ContentCollectionRepository {
    private final List<Content> contentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ContentCollectionRepository() {
    }

    public List<Content> findAll() {
        return contentList;
    }

    public Optional<Content> findById(Integer id) {  // Optional -> may or may not be null
        return contentList.stream().filter(c -> c.getId().equals(id)).findFirst();
    }

    public void save(Content content) {
        contentList.removeIf(c -> c.getId().equals(content.getId())); // remove data on the Id
        contentList.add(content); // replace with updated data on the same Id
    }

//    public void updateById(Integer id, Content content) {
//        contentList.set(id - 1, content);
//    }

    public boolean existsById(Integer id) {
        return contentList.stream().filter(c -> c.getId().equals(id)).count() == 1; // does id exist?
    }

    public void delete(Integer id) {
        contentList.removeIf(c -> c.getId().equals(id));
    }

    @PostConstruct // initialize dependency injection
    private void init() {
        Content c = new Content(
                1,
                "My First Blog Post",
                "My first blog post",
                Status.IDEA,
                Type.ARTICLE,
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                null,
                ""
        );

        contentList.add(c);
    }


}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password= 123

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

Columns did get added in postgres so it kinda works but not the apis.

Error logs

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists content add column desc varchar(255)" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:608) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.project.test.example.TestExampleApplication.main(TestExampleApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "desc"
  Position: 42
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted

2023-05-28T19:10:25.081+05:00  INFO 18920 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-05-28T19:10:25.102+05:00  INFO 18920 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-28T19:10:25.865+05:00  WARN 18920 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-05-28T19:10:26.703+05:00  INFO 18920 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-05-28T19:10:26.719+05:00  INFO 18920 --- [           main] c.p.test.example.TestExampleApplication  : Started TestExampleApplication in 8.905 seconds (process running for 9.688)
2023-05-28T19:10:34.817+05:00  INFO 18920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-28T19:10:34.817+05:00  INFO 18920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-28T19:10:34.817+05:00  INFO 18920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2023-05-28T19:10:35.100+05:00  WARN 18920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.project.test.example.model.Content` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)]
2023-05-28T19:10:43.732+05:00  WARN 18920 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
2023-05-28T19:10:43.732+05:00 ERROR 18920 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column c1_0.desc does not exist
  Position: 52
2023-05-28T19:10:43.749+05:00 ERROR 18920 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select c1_0.id,c1_0.date_created,c1_0.date_updated,c1_0.desc,c1_0.status,c1_0.title,c1_0.type,c1_0.url from content c1_0]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column c1_0.desc does not exist
  Position: 52
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1073) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:403) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy116.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: is it ok `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")`? in your request you are sending the request to `http://localhost:8080`. Is there any log error message with an stacktrace?

Comment: removing cross origins also doesn't do anything. Here's the error log:

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists content add column desc varchar(255)" via JDBC Statement
 
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
 
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]

 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal
`

Comment: please, edit your post and paste the log message using the proper formatting like you did with the java classes. same for the http requests. instead of pasting a link to an external resource, put the http request with the corresponding method, header and body and what was the response. The comments doesn't offer good formatting and has limited characters. I suggest to read the article [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: as per oyur attached image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jac5U.png and error message, the column 'desc' does not exist so either add column 'desc' in content table or remove the field 'desc' from entity class

Comment: @Abhishek get is working after removing 'desc' from entity. But post still gives error 400 Bad Request. I'm sending this as JSON 
`[
    {
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "title",
    "status" : "",
    "type" : "",
    "dateCreated" : "2023-05-28T14:39:46.385+00:00",
    "dateUpdated" : "",
    "url" : ""

    }
]`

Comment: is there any exception?

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: check my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/76352168/7012221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, Staus and Type are enum. if yes, you have to use **@JsonCreator** in your enum as jackson couldn't use enum constructor, you can create static method instead which will lookup value from string for you. For example, put below code in your enums.

```
    @JsonCreator
public static Status fromString(String status) {
    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        return null;
    }
    return Status.valueOf(status);
}
```

with above changes it's working for me.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I didn't know it was the enums that were causing trouble. I'm new to Spring Boot but the community is awesome! Thanks again.

Comment: Tried, but I need 15 reputation :/ I'll be back to upvote once I get the damn 15 reputation xD Thanks again for helping out

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a reserved word in Postgres.

Proposal:

```
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "description")
    String desc;
```

`ContentController.saveCon` expects one `Content` object, but your POST request body is sending a list `[{ ... }]`.

Comment: Yes thank you, I fixed that. But POST is not working. It says error 400 bad request even though I'm sending this JSON. `[  {     "id" : 1,     "title" : "title",     "status" : "",     "type" : "",     "dateCreated" :"",     "dateUpdated" : "",     "url" : ""      } ]`

Comment: I did send a single object `{ }` but still error 400. If I just send the `id` and `title` it gives an error 500